# Drag and drop with in parent div

Tags: jquery

I have to drag the search box with in its parent div
Eg:-

Parent div
 children div

I have to drag children div with in parent div

Please suggest some link or answer

Comment: What have you tried? I'd suggest starting with the jQuery UI draggable and droppable stuff: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: your question is most likely to get closed..unless you provide us with some code or the codes that you have tried.... atleast html structure of parent and child

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Actually use this code only i finished the drag and drop option.but through out the document search box is drag i need to limit the move

Comment: <html>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="search>
     </div>
</div>
</html>

The div element with search id is not drag exceedd the div element with parent id

Comment: @AnandaKrishnan Can you see the answer, and it has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**jQuery UI Draggable**](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) features the thing which you need. So, basically you need to have a parent `.parent` and a draggable child, `.child`.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Drag Me!</div>
</div>
```

Then call the script, and make sure you include `containment: "parent"` to contain it within its parent:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".child" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
});
```

To see the movement, you can add some borders and height.

```
.parent {width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #999;}
.child {width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/B2akk/

---

For your HTML, the parent is `#parent` and the draggable child is `#search`.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="search"> </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code for the same would be:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#search" ).draggable({ containment: "#parent" });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ds4pv/

Comment: Your `containment` should be the selector of the parent element.

Comment: What have you done? Without knowing the full code, css and html structure, we cannot say anything.

Comment: Why did you give this link?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement See the **constrain movement** section please.

Comment: That should be *noted. :)